# "You need to fix your Microsoft account" notification, but no account

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-account

Dears,

After changing my Microsoft Account password online, my Windows 10 build 17134.471 started occasionally complaining about me having to fix my Microsoft account. It would appear that Windows Update Client is somehow connected because notifications about updates have mysteriously disappeared after that (they do appear when I manually check for updates).

I know full well of the [Superuser question with almost identical heading](https://superuser.com/questions/1123583/you-need-to-fix-your-microsoft-account-notification), but the assumption there is that the person is logging in with that account or has, at some point, logged in with that account. I do not.

I will use my Microsoft account on the rare occasion I sign in using Firefox to a Microsoft service, otherwise the computer runs only on the local account.

Now, the problem boils down to this: clicking Windows, typing `email` and then choosing `Your email & app account settings`, choosing the Microsoft account and clicking `Remove` DOES remove the account, but it will REAPPEAR within a certain time, which I believe to be less than 12 hours.

The question: how do I get rid of the account for good?

Edit: [by popular demand, image of the error message.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tfE0.png)

Comment: A screenshot of the error message should help.

Comment: We experience this on our domain, do you use office 365, or have you signed into the Microsoft store? In our case office 365 triggers this notification when a password has changed. It is likely a service in windows that you have signed into is triggering this. (Not just the Windows account itself).

Comment: Thanks for the insight on Office 365. However, I use Office 2013. I have possibly accessed Office 365 e-mail via a Web browser but appwiz.cpl shows nothing O365wise installed.

Comment: Going through `HKCU` and looking for the e-mail address associated with the offending Microsoft account, I found exactly one match at `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\IdentityCRL\UserExtendedProperties\<e-mail address>`. I exported the key and then deleted it.

This does not help.