# Removing Microsoft Account Without Access To Said Account

Tags: user-accounts

There have been similar posts in the past, e.g. ["You need to fix your Microsoft account" notification](https://superuser.com/questions/1123583/you-need-to-fix-your-microsoft-account-notification). This post, however, did not have the extra caveat which is that, in my situation, I no longer have access to the account I am trying to delete. That is, I have been blocked. I'm assuming this is because this was an account for a summer internship I recently finished. Is there any way to now remove this account without contacting the company? Again, I have no access because they've cut me off.

What struck me as odd is that the above linked post said to simply click on the account in question and hit remove... yet this is no longer an option and it seems as though I'll need to log in to remove it.

[image]

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - Microsoft isn't going to be able to help unlink a Microsoft account from a personal computer linked to a business account.  The simplest option would be to create a new local user and manually transfer the data from the other profile.